# How can i enable scrolling in my popup window

Tags: javascript

```
$('a.poptrigger').click( function(){
        popID = $(this).attr('data-rel');
        $('#' + popID).fadeIn();
        var popMargTop = ($('#' + popID).height()) / 2;
        var popMargLeft = ($('#' + popID).width()) / 2;
        $('#' + popID).css({
            'margin-top' : -popMargTop,
            'margin-left' : -popMargLeft
        });
        $('body').append("<div id='fade'></div>");
        $('#fade').fadeTo("slow", 0.70);

        if($(this).attr('data-rel')=='addleague'  && !map){
            initialize();
        }

        if($(this).attr('data-rel')=='addorganization' && !map2){
            initialize2();
        }

        return false;
    });
```

This is my function which is responsible for popup but when i scroll the screen below the popup gets scroll i want to get scrolling in my popup 
can anyone suggest me how can i get that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made my own solution. Hope it works for you.

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow-x: visible;
overflow-y: hidden;
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L46kh0y6/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

```css
overflow: scroll;
```

for the popup window? just add

```
$('#'+ popID).css('overflow','scroll');
```

Comment: using this i am only getting horizontal scrolling but i want vertical scrolling

Comment: Try to include `text-wrap:none;` to your CSS?

Comment: Try overflow-y: scroll;